# Rails 4 - Creating a settings page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I currently have users set up with Devise. I want to add a settings page that belongs to a user for business settings , and I have been reading that it is better to keep the User model as clean as possible. How can I create a page that has a form with "company Name", "Company Phone", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an Account, Customer or Company model that relates to the user(s) model(s).

If a Company is supossed to have several users then maybe users `belongs_to` a Company and the company would `have_many` users. In this case only Company admins would be able to update Company information.

If a Company will have only one user then the Company would `belongs_to :user` and the user would `have_one :company` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :company`. From your question I think this is the one you will need.

With `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you can then update company details in your forms using `field_for`

When using devise I usually go with a '/profile' resource page where you can put your settings forms.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm more concerned about the controller and view. Rails 4 uses strong parameters which im not quite understanding yet. I created a User_settings controller with an index action, but im not exactly sure what to put in there. My Setting table has "user_id", "company_name", "company_phone", etc. but im not sure how to call all of that and put in into a form.